# List all JPopupMenu currently shown

Tags: java, swing

How to get a list of all JPopupMenu components currently shown on the screen.
Or get all JPopupMenu components that then could be filtered by visibility, validity etc.
I need this for writing tests. Stuck on JPopupMenu-s is not part of parent-child (container-component) relations.

Comment: beware: it's shown in a separate window only if it is heavyweight, by default, that's only the case if it a portion of its area is outside the top-level ancestor of its owner. If it's lightweigt, it's shown in the popup layer of the rootPane's layeredPane

Comment: forgot: wondering - why are you expecting several popups? as a general rule, there is exactly one popup (which still needs to be found :-) visible at any given time. Te one exception to that rule are submenus - which might well be what you are after. At the end, the why question seems to boil down to: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPopupMenu is Window and it is listed in java.awt.Window.getWindows()

Answer (score 2):

For all unit tests with swing we use the Fest framework. There is a popup menu fixture that will allow you to test stuff on the popup menu.

https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-swing-1.x

Using the framework I am sure you can search for all popup menus shown by searching with the name you set for the JPopupMenu.

EDIT: 
The framework maintenance changed hands a few years ago. Please check before using it.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

As comments show this is not trivial as effected by light and heavyweight concerns... For example in some cases JPopupMenu can be nested inside a JRootPane. However this in an alternative public API that be used - javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager which can be used to get list of JPopupMenus. I found this inside `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI.getPopups()`

```
static List<JPopupMenu> getPopups() {
    MenuSelectionManager msm = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager();
    MenuElement[] p = msm.getSelectedPath();

    List<JPopupMenu> list = new ArrayList<JPopupMenu>(p.length);
    for (MenuElement element : p) {
        if (element instanceof JPopupMenu) {
            list.add((JPopupMenu) element);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Original solution using Window.getWindows()

```
private boolean isPopupMenuOpen() {
    for (Window each : Window.getWindows()) {
        if (findPopup(each) != null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private JPopupMenu findPopup(Component root) {
    if (root instanceof JPopupMenu) {
        return (JPopupMenu) root;
    }
    if (root instanceof JWindow) {
        return findPopup(((JWindow)root).getContentPane());
    }
    if (root instanceof JRootPane) {
        return findPopup(((JRootPane)root).getLayeredPane());
    }
    if (root instanceof Container) {
        for (Component each : ((Container) root).getComponents()) {
            return findPopup(each);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: is it intended that in your Container iteration you immediately return with the first result? I guess you wanted to return with the first non-null result